# node: relocation error: node: symbol SSL_set_cert_cb, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, centos7, npm-install

I've been running a NodeJS server for a website using the MEAN stack for a website, and it's been running for a few months. When I started to work on it again this morning, I started up the website with:

```
nodemon server/app.js
```

The express server starts up just fine, but as soon as I connect to it with my browser, I get the following error:

> node: relocation error: node: symbol SSL_set_cert_cb, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference
>   [nodemon] failed to start process, "node" exec not found`

And when I do `node server/app.js`, I get the same `node: relocation error...`, but dont' get the `...failed to start process...`

I don't think it is with any changes I made in the past few days, because I went to another server where this was running on (where the code was a few weeks old), and I restarted the nodejs process, and then it broke when I accessed the site.

npm version: 3.10.10, 
node version: 6.11.3,
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611

Comment: I am getting this exact error as well, trying to run my CI/CD pipeline... I will let you know if I find a fix.

Comment: I am getting the same error when I run `npm install grunt`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I had same issue with a ursa module that on the same environment.

Npm rebuild has the following error when my `openssl` version is `1.0.1e`

`node-gyp: relocation error: node-gyp: symbol SSL_set_cert_cb, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference`

I updated openssl with `yum update openssl` to `1.0.2k`, then `npm rebuild` no longer has that error.

Comment: Thank you, after `yum update openssl` I could successfully execute `npm install grunt` again. Does anyone know the cause of the error? This happened suddenly without any configuration changes.

Comment: I also fixed this my updating my npm to 5.3.0 and node to 8.2.1

Comment: This fixed it for me as well; I'm guessing that CentOS updated and caused this issue; I've had that happen a couple of times in the past--we only lock it to a major version, which is a problem, I see.

Comment: Same as Mike K., I upgraded to node 7.10.1 and npm 4.2.0, works now.  Likely broke due to an automated upgrade couple of days ago.  The 'fix' got lots of confusing dependency errors (with npm, so I did nodejs first), but worked.

Comment: When openssl is updated using *yum update openssl*, issue of _npm: relocation error: npm: symbol SSL_set_cert_cb, version libssl.so.10 not defined in file libssl.so.10 with link time reference_ got resolved.

Comment: Works with error when starting squid proxy: `/usr/sbin/squid: relocation error: /usr/sbin/squid: symbol SSL_set_alpn_protos, version libssl.so.10 not defined in f...e reference`

Answer (score 0):

Run: $yum update if nothing works